# Zend Framework 2 / ZF 2 - create own Element-Template for Inputs and Collections and so on

Tags: forms, collections, zend-framework2

i've got a little problem here and i am searching already all across the web:

i have a Formcollection in zf2. i use $this->formCollection()->renderTemplate() in my view to get a generated template.

How can i replace the standard template from zf2?

greetz

Comment: Too lazy to answer as it's easily done: see [my simple gist](https://gist.github.com/manuakasam/64f569b170acb72755e2). In short, you can't change the `renderTemplate()` output, you simply copy-paste your HTML markup and just write plain HTML ;)

Comment: i already though about this. BUT(!) in the original-markup there are additional fields i have to filter, there are already events on elements i have to unbind etc...  that's why it would be easier to change the templatescript i though...

but i think - if i really wanna do this - have to edit the template of every single element i used in this collection!(???)

Comment: As i said, it's not possible. The ViewHelpers provide a Default rendering which is `formCollection()` and you can always override. In case of the collection-template-markup, that you either have to stick with the default or render it manually, there's no way around it as far as i know. Bakura at #zftalk may have more insight but i highly doubt it's possible

Answer (score -3):

In standard zf2 render you can do:

```
// Blog section
$blogView = new ViewModel();    
$blogView->setTemplate('pages/index/blog.phtml'); // change the default template
return $blogView;
```

Comment: The question is regarding form collection templates not view templates